# html5:how to make poster image to be displayed in android 4.0.4 devices?

Tags: html

I'm using html5  to display/play the videos on android devices. But image set through "poster" tag is not displayed. How to make it displayed? Or is there any alternate solution to have a preview image for the html5 videos ?

```
<video width="100%" height="350" preload="none" controls="controls" poster="img path"> 
 <source src="mp4 image path" type="video/mp4"> 
 <source src="ogv image path" type="video/ogv"> 
 <source src="mov image path" type="video/mov">
 <source src="webm image path" type="video/webm"> 
</video>
```

Comment: Be sure to check the source of image to make verify the path is correct and/or it exists. Otherwise try adding some code snippets or a js fiddle link to get a better answer.

Comment: <video width="100%" height="350" preload="none" controls="controls" poster="img path">
 <source src="mp4 image path" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="ogv image path" type="video/ogv">
 <source src="mov image path" type="video/mov">
 <source src="webm image path" type="video/webm">
</video> this is the syntax im using to display videos on the site

Comment: Image path is perfect. Im able to view the same image on a new window but not as a poster image.